# Remove [eid]_[hash] in AppData

Tags: c#, appdata, user.config

Just a hobby and not well-verse in C#.

**Here's the problem:**
The user.config of my executable is stored in the ...\Executable Name_[eid]_[hash]. This would be great if the user opens up my executable in ONE location.

However, since the user may open the executable in a temporary directory (say Downloads), and relocate the executable to a permanent location later, it will generate a new directory with different [eid] and [hash], for the executable in the Downloads.

I've been wrecking my brain, and searching up for a solution, but nothing.